# How to reset fetch-mock for each test?

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs, fetch, fetch-mock

I have several React tests using Jest and [`fetch-mock`](https://github.com/wheresrhys/fetch-mock), each one of them doing some get operations, so what I initially did was:

```
beforeAll(){
    fetchMock.get(`*`, JSON.stringify(CORRECTRESPONSE));
}
```

However, in some tests I need to return wrong data as answer, something like:

```
test('Wrong get answer', ()=> {
   fetchMock.get('*', JSON.stringify(WRONGRESPONSE), {overwriteRoutes: true});
}));
```

So, since I need to reset the response for the following tests (and so return `CORRECTRESPONSE`, I came up with this solution:

```
beforeEach(){
    fetchMock.get(`*`, JSON.stringify(CORRECTRESPONSE));
}

afterEach(fetchMock.restore);
```

Is there anyway better to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the docs this should do it

```
beforeEach(() => {
  fetch.resetMocks()
})
```

Comment: Please cite your source

Answer (score 4):

I don't understand why the previous answer (https://stackoverflow.com/a/49778196/689944) was set as correct. Cleanup up after tests by `afterEach(fetchMock.restore)` is a very good way.

That's also what is described in the fetch-mock documentation: http://www.wheresrhys.co.uk/fetch-mock/#api-lifecyclerestore_reset